# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator - Invalid SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, localhost, certificate, azure-cosmosdb

Normally I would launch Azure Cosmos DB Emulator.exe (installed on Windows 10) and it would launch Chrome at https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.htm saying "Congratulations! Your Azure Cosmos DB emulator is running.", easy peasy. But today I have an issue, it resulted with Chrome saying the SSL Certificate is invalid, Firefox too.

[image: chrome error]

[image: firefox error]

In an attempt to start again I've tried the following:

- uninstalling the emulator
- going to `certlm.msc` deleting all certificates called 'localhost'
- deleting the folder at `AppData\Local\CosmosDBEmulator`
- restarting my Windows machine
- reinstalling

Same happens. Every time I re-install and run the emulator, it adds a couple of 'localhost' certificates behind the scenes (below), but they don't seem to be trusted based on what the browser is saying. Based on the names, the ones in **Trusted Root Certificate Authorities** seem to match up with the certificates in **Personal**. These must be self-signed certs the browser is complaining about ?? (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not an expert on this). I also tried a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyQ9IIxE3vc) on getting a certificate trusted via exporting/importing the certificate, but that did nothing either.

[image: certificates in Personal]
[image: certificates in Trusted Root Certificate Authorities]

Is it possible that I can get my browsers to see these certificates as valid? Just want it to work like before - running the emulator and have localhost work on any browser without the need to mess with certificates or any browser settings. Any help appreciated!

Comment: i also have the same problem

Comment: hey @fabriciols I decided to move forward as there's not much help (yet) and it's not worth spending anymore of my time on it. SO the short-term solution was to just allow insure certificates for localhost on Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31900210/2738219
It allowed me to carry on my work without the need to switch to Firefox and proceeding to accept the "risk" on every launch.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue. I could not fix it yet, but when I opened it with Microsoft Edge it worked flawlessly. I hope this helps you get going.

Comment: It is working again in Chrome, with the latest version. Maybe check your version of it.

Answer (score 10):

Simple solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646463/8665500

Just type '***thisisunsafe***' on the danger page, and it proceeds to the page

Comment: In my comment I provided a link from the same thread, they mention this as an alternative solution. Is it a persisted action? otherwise I'm not sure if typing 'thisisunsafe' everytime localhost fires up is the best solution vs chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: I think every time you close the chrome, and you want to open "Data explorer" you have to type the cheat-code, anyway I always prefer to type the cheat-code, not an issue at all

Answer (score 6):

In Chrome, enable allow insecure localhost:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

And for Edge, the same flag is here:

```
edge://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```